# Upload an Image to Database from Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-database, django-models

Here is my model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Flower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/media')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        url(r'^$', 'site1.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^mysite1/', include('mysite1.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from site1.models import Flower

admin.site.register(Flower)
```

Full Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1233.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  85.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  291.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  763.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  818.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  344.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/site1/flower/
Exception Value: no such column: site1_flower.image
```

I want to upload images to my site database from admin panel, so I can view this images anywhere I want.
But I'm suffering an error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/site1/flower/
no such column: site1_flower.image
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/site1/flower/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
no such column: site1_flower.image
```

How can I surmount this problem.

Comment: Your model looks good. Can you provide more details - like full traceback, how you are trying to access it? Why is there site1 in url?

Comment: Still can't help with above information. Can you give directory structure and code inside admin.py?

Comment: Yeah, as Sholomitcky said - I guess you added ImageField after you did syncdb. Clear the db and do syncdb again. You should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to *Exception Value: no such column: site1_flower.image*
I suppose, u've added image field after syncdb. So, image field doesn't exists at db.
Easiest way is to remove Flower model at all and run syncdb again.
Or you may create this field manually at your db.
But the best way is to use [django south](http://south.aeracode.org/)